# Javascript methods at global scope mappings

Tags: javascript, parsing, global

We use a bit of javascript that overwrites the setTimeout method for IE. This is because in some versions of IE the parameters do not get passed correctly (see [here](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2007/06/simple-settimeout-setinterval-extra.html)).

I have to load the modified setTimeout script first, because if I load it after the code that calls setTimeout is parsed (not run) then the modifed version does not get called.

***What happens when the javascript engine parses files that have method calls to methods at the global scope? Do the mappings to the methods get created at parse time or when the code is executed?***

**EDIT**

I have had a few answers to this question, which give other solutions to this problem, but the problem at hand is not my concern as I already have a solution for it. What I want to gain by this question is a better understanding of how javascript is parsed and run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT #2**

Fiddle #1 - http://jsfiddle.net/zEaL8/4/ - Allows you to set/reset a native function. To see how the redefinition and calling order works.

Fiddle #2 - http://jsfiddle.net/aKnjA/1/ -Demonstrates that the order of definition does not matter. Notice that the redefinition happens after the browser parses the call to the function.

**EDIT**

To answer your question: Javascript does not enforce any order of definition of functions. i.e. we can call a function defined afterwards in code. When the browser parses a line of code that calls a function that is defined afterwards, it does not have any clue as to where to find that function. This being the case, it is clear that binding happens only at run-time and not during initial parse. This in effect would mean that your redefinition of setTimeout is what will execute. The only thing to ensure is that the redefinition of setTimeout itself gets executed before any call to that is executed.

To ensure that the redefinition of your new setTimeout is processed first, you can place it in a script block as the first element inside the head node outside load, domReady etc.

i.e. Something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.setTimeout = function() {
    alert('new sT');
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setTimeout();"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, but this does not answer the question i asked which is about the parsing and mapping of javascript methods

Comment: if what you have said is true then i should not have experienced the behaviour i am seeing, i.e. the code that was parsed before the new setTimeout method calling the default method as it was run after the replacement setTimeout method was parsed, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Methods  are created at when the code is executed.

If the semantics of the code is correct interpreter is able to execute code.
While parsing nothing wasn't be executed.
File after parsing is executed singly one by one , before parsing the next.

Check this out:
 We have two js files.

```
<script src ='1.js'></script>  
<script src ='2.js'></script>
```

In second file we put declaration of setTimeout;

```
 //file2
 window.setTimeout = function(){};
```

In first file we'll checking for setTimeout being overridden

```
//file1
var f = function() { alert( setTimeout );  };
f();// alerts native setTimeout

 setTimeout( f, 1000 ); // We use native settimeout, propably after one second file2 being loaded and executed and function `f` will be alerts the overriden setTimeout
```

If methods which I added  were would be created during parsing. This would have access to it anywhere in the script in which it was created, even before its declaration. 
so:

```
//somefile.js
  setTimeout(); // we do not have access to function declared below, so while parsing  this wasn't created.
  window.setTimeout = function() { alert( 'whatever' ); }
```

Comment: yes, but this does not answer the question i asked which is about the parsing and mapping of javascript methods

Answer (score 0):

you can store original setTimeout in a global variable at the beginning of the code and then overload the setTimeot with a new function.

```
 window.oldST = setTimeout;
 window.setTimeout = function(funct,x) {
    return oldST(funct,x);
 }
```

so if these are the first lines of the js code you will have overloaded the setTimeout function with yours and set the old one in oldST.

Comment: yes, but this does not answer the question i asked which is about the parsing and mapping of javascript methods

Comment: The mapping is created at the execution of the code not at parse time, this should've been the answer.